# No module named 'psutil'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Пытаюсь запустить бота telegram, пишет:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Аля\Desktop\catbot\bot.py", line 15, in 
> import psutil ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'

Я погуглил и начал устанавливать **pip install psutil**
И вот тут проблема.

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\Аля\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u
> -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Temp\pip-install-rv5buiyf\psutil_4f7a918e77454480abb6e99e17a3b165\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Temp\pip-install-rv5buiyf\psutil_4f7a918e77454480abb6e99e17a3b165\setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record 'C:\Temp\pip-record-epo_q50y\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Аля\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil'
> cwd: C:\Temp\pip-install-rv5buiyf\psutil_4f7a918e77454480abb6e99e17a3b165
> Complete output (38 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> copying psutil_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> copying psutil_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> copying psutil_psaix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> copying psutil_psbsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> copying psutil_pslinux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> copying psutil_psosx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> copying psutil_psposix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> copying psutil_pssunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> copying psutil_pswindows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> copying psutil_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_aix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_bsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_contracts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_linux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_memleaks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_osx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_process.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_sunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_system.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_testutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests\test_windows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> copying psutil\tests_*main*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
> running build_ext
> building 'psutil._psutil_windows' extension
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> 'C:\Users\Аля\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u
> -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Temp\pip-install-rv5buiyf\psutil_4f7a918e77454480abb6e99e17a3b165\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Temp\pip-install-rv5buiyf\psutil_4f7a918e77454480abb6e99e17a3b165\setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record 'C:\Temp\pip-record-epo_q50y\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Аля\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil'
> Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: написано, что нужно установить vs build tools для сборки расширения.

Comment: Ссылка в ошибке

Comment: А что это ? **Microsoft C++ Build Tools**  что оно мне даст после установки? @Рамис

Comment: А что это ? **Microsoft C++ Build Tools**  что оно мне даст после установки? @xmikex

Comment: @Erik, это просто перевод того что там написано: 
*ошибка расширения: требуется Microsoft Visual C ++ 14.0 или выше. Получите это с помощью «Microsoft C ++ Build Tools»:*

Comment: Erik, оно даст возможность собрать расширение конкретно подходящее вам. Вообще обычно бинарные пакеты готовые ставятся через pip, но возможно конкретно подходящего для вас там не было, поэтому надо собирать из исходников.